# Calling javascript synchronously after making ajax call for the new content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using ajax call to refresh the div content from a new jsp. there are some  tags which I am calling asynchronously through call which is why they are not working. ( tags are not working). how do I make them synchronized while displaying.

My idea is through document.write(code). But its not working out. Can any body suggest a solution to this please.

Comment: You need to show some code or explain better - you don't "call tags" in javascript, you "call functions" ... so, code will make your meaning clearer - p.s. don't use `document.write` unless you're writing code for Netscape 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `document.write()` in an Ajax callback or in any asynchronous callback. You can only use it during the initial page load. If you call `document.write()` after the page has loaded (e.g. in an Ajax callback) it will wipe the entire page contents before writing the data.

If you're using jQuery, the `load()` method is an easy way to fetch data from a server and insert into an element on your page. An example from [the `load()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

That will download the `ajax/test.html` page from your server and insert its content into the element whose `id` is `result`.

`load()` is a convenience wrapper around [the `$.ajax()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). For more options, error handling and such, you can call `$.ajax()` directly, as in the example below. This should give similar results to the above when it succeeds, but it writes an error message if the server call fails:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/test.html"
})
.done(function( html ) {
    $( "#result" ).html( html );
})
.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    $( "#result" ).html( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```